# How to add custom index using ingest node pipeline?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

Is it possible to create conditional indexing by using ingest node pipelines? I feel this could be done by the script processor but can someone tell if this is possible?

I am in a scenario where I should decide which is a better way to do custom indexing. I can mention conditions in the metricbeat.yml /filebeat.yml files to get this done. But is this the best way to do custom indexing? There is no logstash in my elastic stack

```yaml
output.elasticsearch:
          indices:
            - index: "metricbeat-dev-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
              when.equals:
                kubernetes.namespace: "dev"
```

This is how I have implemented custom indexing in metric/filebeat right now. I have like 20+ namespaces in my Kubernetes cluster. Please help in suggesting if this could be done by ingest node pipeline or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can achived this by ingest pipeline Set Processor. Ingest Pipeline support [accessing of metadata fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html#access-metadata-fields) and you can access / update index name using _index field name.

Below is sample Ingest Pipeline which will update index name when namespace is dev:

```json
[
  {
    "set": {
      "field": "_index",
      "value": "metricbeat-dev",
      "if": "ctx.kubernetes?.namespace== 'dev'"
    }
  }
]
```

Upadte 1: append agent version to index name. I ahve consider agent version feild name as `agent.version`

```json
[
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "_index",
          "value": "metricbeat-dev-{{agent.version}}",
          "if": "ctx.kubernetes?.namespace== 'dev'"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: When i implement this in my metricbeat.yml I am getting the index as .ds-metricbeat-dev any idea why it is creating a data stream?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar I am not exectly sure but it might be happening as your index name is starting with metricbeat- which is matching with the existing ILM and index template. Please raise seperate question for this.

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar Please accept my answer if it is helped you.

Comment: This is not exactly what i want but still works but its not creating an alias and stuff so am not able to implement ilm

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar are you trying with metricbeat- index name or other custom inex name

Comment: data is from metricbeat in my OpenShift cluster and I want a custom index at the namespace level. currently, all data from different namespaces comes to single index I wanted to come in different index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240001/discussion-between-sagar-patel-and-sidharth-vijayakumar).